# Change background-image of specific item in knockout foreach through javascript function

Tags: indexing, knockout.js, foreach

I am using a knockout foreach to display a list of game boards. The game board has a class/Id of "gameBoard.

I want to be able to change the background image of just the game board that detects a score change.

Problem is when the foreach generates the boards they all get the same class/Id name so there's no way to strictly reference that individual board. Changing the background once the homeTeamScore.observables subscribe method is fired is probably the easiest bet and that's set up but I do not know how to reference the board.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: collection">
<div id="gameBoardTemplate" type="text/html">
    <div id="gameBoard" data-bind="visible: IsVisible">
        <div class="gameHeader">
            <h1 class="gameNameHeader" data-bind="text:'Game ' + GameChannel()"></h1>
        </div> <!-- End of game header -->
        .............. etc
```

line 3 above is the div I want to change the background of

Below is a copy of some of the knockout and javascript stuff.

```
var Board = function (gameChannel, homeTeamImage, homeTeamName, homeBeerPrice, homeTeamArrow, homeBeer, homeBeerAdjustedPrice, homeTeamScore, awayTeamArrow, awayBeerPrice, awayTeamName, awayBeerAdjustedPrice, awayBeer, awayTeamImage, awayTeamScore, isVisible) {
    this.GameChannel = ko.observable(gameChannel);
    this.HomeTeamImage = ko.observable(homeTeamImage);
    this.HomeTeamName = ko.observable(homeTeamName);
    this.HomeBeerPrice = ko.observable(homeBeerPrice);
    this.HomeTeamArrow = ko.observable(homeTeamArrow);
    this.HomeBeer = ko.observable(homeBeer);
    this.HomeBeerAdjustedPrice = ko.observable(homeBeerAdjustedPrice);
    this.HomeTeamScore = ko.observable(homeTeamScore);
    this.AwayTeamArrow = ko.observable(awayTeamArrow);
    this.AwayBeerPrice = ko.observable(awayBeerPrice);
    this.AwayTeamName = ko.observable(awayTeamName);
    this.AwayBeerAdjustedPrice = ko.observable(awayBeerAdjustedPrice);
    this.AwayBeer = ko.observable(awayBeer);
    this.AwayTeamImage = ko.observable(awayTeamImage);
    this.AwayTeamScore = ko.observable(awayTeamScore);
    this.IsVisible = ko.observable(isVisible);

    this.FullScore = ko.computed(function () { return this.HomeTeamScore() + " | " + this.AwayTeamScore(); }, this);

    this.HomeTeamScore.subscribeChanged(function (newScore, oldScore) {
        if (oldScore.localeCompare("") == -1) {
            showTouchdownAnimation();
        }
    });

    this.AwayTeamScore.subscribeChanged(function (newScore, oldScore) {
        if (oldScore.localeCompare("") == -1) {
            showTouchdownAnimation();
        }
    }); 
}

//This gets populated through an ajax call so its not always blank. Assume its always populated correctly
var viewModel = {
// Game board placeholders
collection: [
    new Board("0", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",false),
    new Board("0", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",false)
]
};


ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

I want to reference the exact board that fired the HomeTeamScore() subscribe method and change the background but how do I do that when all boards get given the same class and ID names when the foreach loop iterates and creates them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could simply apply a CSS class when either the home or away score is > 0, using the `css` binding:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: collection">
<div id="gameBoardTemplate" type="text/html">
    <div id="gameBoard" data-bind="visible: IsVisible, css: { 'HomeTeamScored': HomeTeamScore() > 0, 'AwayTeamScored': AwayTeamScore() > 0 }">
```

(I'm sure you're aware element ID's need to be unique, so you should probably change the ID's to classes here.)

Another way would be to make the background image a property of your Board model, and utilize the `style` binding in your template. Then you could manipulate it in the functions that gets executed when the score changes. Like so (removed irrelevant code for brevity):

```
var Board = function (gameChannel, homeTeamImage, homeTeamName, homeBeerPrice, homeTeamArrow, homeBeer, homeBeerAdjustedPrice, homeTeamScore, awayTeamArrow, awayBeerPrice, awayTeamName, awayBeerAdjustedPrice, awayBeer, awayTeamImage, awayTeamScore, isVisible) {
    var self = this;
    ...
    this.BGImage = ko.observable(null);

    this.HomeTeamScore.subscribeChanged(function (newScore, oldScore) {
        if (oldScore.localeCompare("") == -1) {
            showTouchdownAnimation();
            self.BGImage("Huzzah.jpg");
        }
    });
}
```

Template:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: collection">
    <div class="gameBoardTemplate" type="text/html">
        <div class="gameBoard" data-bind="visible: IsVisible, style: { backgroudImage: BGImage }">
```

Comment: This is close but my background image needs to be dynamic and decided within a javascript function so it cannot be hard coded into the html. So when a subscribe change is detected in the viewmodel I want to assign that affected item a new background image but leave all other items alone. This is just hard when the ko.foreach generates all boards with the same class names and ID's

Comment: In that case, see my edit for some added code that should put you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a reference to `this`, so that only the corresponding view-model is affected. So I created the `self` variable to reference `this` inside your subscribe function.

Now you can call the `isVisible` observable of the relevant view-model and change its value to `true`.

I've made a snippet for clarity. By the way, I changed 'gameBoard' to be a class instead of an id. Ids have to be unique and will not work correctly for `foreach`.

```js
ko.subscribable.fn.subscribeChanged = function(callback, context) {
    var savedValue = this.peek();
    return this.subscribe(function(latestValue) {
        var oldValue = savedValue;
        savedValue = latestValue;
        callback.call(context, latestValue, oldValue);
    });
};

var Board = function (gameChannel, homeTeamImage, homeTeamName, homeBeerPrice, homeTeamArrow, homeBeer, homeBeerAdjustedPrice, homeTeamScore, awayTeamArrow, awayBeerPrice, awayTeamName, awayBeerAdjustedPrice, awayBeer, awayTeamImage, awayTeamScore, isVisible) {
    var self = this;
    this.GameChannel = ko.observable(gameChannel);
    this.HomeTeamImage = ko.observable(homeTeamImage);
    this.HomeTeamName = ko.observable(homeTeamName);
    this.HomeBeerPrice = ko.observable(homeBeerPrice);
    this.HomeTeamArrow = ko.observable(homeTeamArrow);
    this.HomeBeer = ko.observable(homeBeer);
    this.HomeBeerAdjustedPrice = ko.observable(homeBeerAdjustedPrice);
    this.HomeTeamScore = ko.observable(homeTeamScore);
    this.AwayTeamArrow = ko.observable(awayTeamArrow);
    this.AwayBeerPrice = ko.observable(awayBeerPrice);
    this.AwayTeamName = ko.observable(awayTeamName);
    this.AwayBeerAdjustedPrice = ko.observable(awayBeerAdjustedPrice);
    this.AwayBeer = ko.observable(awayBeer);
    this.AwayTeamImage = ko.observable(awayTeamImage);
    this.AwayTeamScore = ko.observable(awayTeamScore);
    this.IsVisible = ko.observable(isVisible);

    this.FullScore = ko.computed(function () { return this.HomeTeamScore() + " | " + this.AwayTeamScore(); }, this);

    this.HomeTeamScore.subscribeChanged(function (newScore, oldScore) {
        //if (oldScore.localeCompare("") == -1) {
            //showTouchdownAnimation();
            self.IsVisible(true);
            setTimeout(function(){
              self.IsVisible(false);
            },3000);
        //}
    });

    this.AwayTeamScore.subscribeChanged(function (newScore, oldScore) {
        //if (oldScore.localeCompare("") == -1) {
            //showTouchdownAnimation();
            self.IsVisible(true);
            setTimeout(function(){
              self.IsVisible(false);
            },3000);

       // }
    }); 
}

//This gets populated through an ajax call so its not always blank. Assume its always populated correctly
var viewModel = {
// Game board placeholders
collection: [
    new Board("0", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",false),
    new Board("1", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",false)
]
};


ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```css
.gameBoard {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.gameBoard::after {
  content: "";
  background: url('http://ayay.co.uk/backgrounds/sports/american_football/38-1024x768.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 200px 200px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>


<div data-bind="foreach: collection">
<div id="gameBoardTemplate" type="text/html">
    <div class="gameBoard" data-bind="visible: IsVisible">
        <div class="gameHeader">
            <h1 class="gameNameHeader" data-bind="text:'Game ' + GameChannel()"></h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input data-bind="value: HomeTeamScore"/>
      <br>
      <input data-bind="value: AwayTeamScore"/>
    </div>
</div>
<br><br>
</div>
```

Comment: This is close but I'm hoping to change the background of the gameBoard class div itself not have a separate image appear. So instead of your added `self.IsVisible(true);` and `setTimeout(function(){....}`functions I need something similar to `self.style.backgroundImage = 'url(.../path/to/pic)`.  

Usually `document.getElementById('gameBoard')` would work but the foreach would give multiple boards with that id, and using `getElementsByClass('gameBoards')` would not work because I only want to affect the 1 board.  Does this clarify?